# json Postman sending raw array

Tags: arrays, json, google-chrome, postman, raw-data

Im just trying send those parameters raw on the postman (chrome extension), but I received that message -> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Im just trying send those parameters raw data:

```
{
    "GUID": "b83354d0-cabd-4a5a-b47f-8cb3d2cb87c6",
    "Produto":["1", "17"],
    "Servico": "202",
    "FormaPagamento": "0",
    "Senha": "12345678",
    "Resposta": "hhd1846"
}
```

Guid is a String, Produto is an Array, Servico is Int, FormaPagamento is Int, Senha is a String and Resposta is a String.

But Im having problems. I belive the problem is in Array

Thanks For your help.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace or sth.? Hard to tell otherwise.

Comment: If FormaPagamento and Servico are supposed to be an int, try removing the "" that's wrapping them. This could also be the problem with Produto if it's an int Array.